# Converting a Go-to statement from FORTRAN 77 to Fortran 90

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran90, fortran77, do-loops

> I am working on a piece of legacy F77 code and trying to convert it
>   to equivalent F90 code. I ran into these lines below and could some
>   one advise if my conversion is correct?

Fortran 77 code:

```
Subroutine area(x,y,z,d)
do 15 j=1,10
if (a.gt.b) go to 20
15 CONTINUE
20 Statement 1
   Statement 2
   Statement 3
end subroutine
```

I tried to convert it to F90 and came up as below:

```
Subroutine area(x,y,z,d)
  dloop: do j=1,10
    if (a>b) then 
      statement 1
      statement 2
      statement 3
    else
      write(*,*) 'Exiting dloop'
      exit dloop
    end if
  end do dloop
end subroutine
```

Could anyone advise if this methodology is correct? In my results, I am not getting the results that I expect. So there could potentially be a problem with my logic.

Comment: Please if you make the effort to modernize some code, use some indentation, otherwise I don't see the point bothering with the translation.

Comment: It's also worth noting: it's already F90 code.

Comment: To make sure that there is nothing missing, you should mention the statements that modify `a` or `b` to make the `if` statement eventually get `.true.`; You can insert just something like `do some computations` in your sample code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the translation slightly wrong... The first step is to rebuild the `do` loop, which loops at `15`:

```
Subroutine area(x,y,z,d)
do j=1,10
  if (a.gt.b) go to 20
enddo
20 Statement 1
   Statement 2
   Statement 3
end subroutine
```

Now you can see that the `goto` results in "jumping out of the loop". In this particular example, this equivalent to an `exit`, and the code can be written as

```
Subroutine area(x,y,z,d)
  do j=1,10
    if (a.gt.b) exit
  enddo
  Statement 1
  Statement 2
  Statement 3
end subroutine
```

Comment: Thanks Vogt, let me try this. However, I am wondering that there is no 'else' condition to that 'if' statement. What would happen if the statement is false?

Comment: If the statement evaluates to FALSE, the loop will continue with its next iteration, until it reaches its limit (in this case 10 iterations).